# How can I download a batch of XML files from a SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to get a set of information that is currently only available as a column of XML data in a SQL server (I'm using MS SQL Server Studio 2008).  My table of interest has a column with a lengthy XML string (~150,000 chars) and is about 20,000 rows tall. My goal is to pull down copies of each XML entry into a separate file in order to flatten the data in post-processing.

I can't figure out how to query over the XML sequentially, though.  It seems like it would make sense to write some kind of script to go through the table and query the XML data one row at a time, then save the text as a .xml file on my disk, and then move on to the next row.

Have you seen any implementations of this idea (querying out one .xml file at a time) before to point to? Do you have any recommendations for how to implement this, or alternate approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are describing using a `cursor` to iterate through the rows, and possibly casting the XML column as a `nvarchar(max)` and using TSQL functions to write the data out to a file (one row/one file at a time).  Never done it, or seen anyone do it, but it certainly sounds doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLDocs (
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,XMLDoc XML NOT NULL
)
GO

; With
    -- number generator by power of 2
    n2(n) as ( SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    n4(n) as ( SELECT 1 FROM n2 t1 CROSS JOIN n2 t2 ),
    n16(n) as ( SELECT 1 FROM n4 t1 CROSS JOIN n4 t2 ),
    n256(n) as ( SELECT 1 FROM n16 t1 CROSS JOIN n16 t2 ),
    n65k(n) as ( SELECT 1 FROM n256 t1 CROSS JOIN n256 t2 ),
   Numbers (n) as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY n) FROM n65k )
INSERT INTO XMLDocs (XMLDoc)
SELECT CAST('<Root><ProductDescription ProductModelID="' 
            + CAST(n as VARCHAR(10)) 
            + '"><Summary>Some Text</Summary></ProductDescription></Root>'
        as XML)
FROM Numbers;
GO
```

Powershell script for export ([MSDN Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx)):

```
# Configuration data 
[string] $server   = "(local)\";       # SQL Server Instance 
[string] $database = "TestDB";     # Database containing the BLOB data. 
[string] $folder   = "D:\Work\XML\";         # Path to export to 
[string] $filename;
[int]    $bufferSize = 32768;               # Stream buffer size in bytes. 


# Select-Statement for file name & blob data with filter. 
$sql = "SELECT 'XMLFile'
        + CAST([ID] as varchar(10))
        + '.XML' as [FileName]
            ,CAST([XMLDoc] as varbinary(MAX)) as [XMLDoc]
        FROM [XMLDocs]
    WHERE [ID] BETWEEN 10 AND 20;"; 

# Open ADO.NET Connection with Windows authentification. 
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection; 
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=True;" 
$con.Open(); 

Write-Output ((Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss) + ": Started ..."); 

# New command and reader 
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $Sql, $con; 
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehavior]::SequentialAccess); 

# Create a byte array for the stream. 
$out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize) 

# Looping through all selected records. 
While ($rd.Read()) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
    $filename = $folder + $rd.GetString(0)
        Write-Output ((Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss) + ": Exporting {0}" -f $filename); 

        # New BinaryWriter; existing file will be overwritten. 
        $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($filename), Create, Write; 
        $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs; 

        $start = 0; 
        # Read first byte stream chunk. 
        $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1); 
        While ($received -gt 0) 
        { 
           $bw.Write($out, 0, $received); 
           $bw.Flush(); 
           $start += $received; 
           # Read next byte stream chunk. 
           $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1); 
        } 

        $bw.Close(); 
        $fs.Close(); 
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        Write-Output ($_.Exception.Message) 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        $fs.Dispose();         
    }         
} 

# Closing & Disposing all objects. 
$rd.Close(); 
$cmd.Dispose(); 
$con.Close(); 

Write-Output ((Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss) + ": Finished.");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was having trouble getting started with PowerShell.  This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is one definite and very easy way to accomplish this, and two potential ways that I don't have time to confirm.

1. The quickest and easiest method that I can think of uses SQLCLR. A CLR-based scalar user-defined function (UDF) that accepts the XML and writes it to a file could be used in a simple SELECT statement. There are various examples across the InterWebs about how to write such a function as well as some pre-done libraries on CodePlex/GitHub/etc (though I cannot speak to the validity of any of that code). One option here, though not a free one, is the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library of SQLCLR functions (of which I am the author). While not expensive, if this is just a one-time use, and if no need for the other functions (there are quite a few, though), then maybe one of the other sources I just mentioned might be the way to go. But, the example below of how to use such a function makes use of SQL# because a) it's what I have, and b) this specific use-case just happens to be one of my demos (as this is not the first request for needing to export XML files), so I thought I would be clear and not misleading.

   As you can see, a simple SELECT is used to create one file per row containing the contents of the XML field. Being a simple SELECT statement allows for easy JOINs and WHERE conditions depending on the needs.

   ```sql
   SELECT SQL#.File_WriteFile(
                N'C:\export\path\' + tab.FieldToUseAsFileName + N'.xml', -- filename
                CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), tab.XmlField), -- file contents
                0, -- Append Data if file already exists?
                NULL -- File Encoding; NULL = Default Encoding
              ) AS [Result]
   FROM dbo.TableName tab;
   ```
2. One potential way is via PowerShell. I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to iterate over the rows of the table, calling a filesystem method to write out the contents.
3. The other potential way is via SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). It has been a few years since I have used SSIS but there is a ForEach container (or something like that) and I thought there was a way to export files.
4. Technically there is another potential method, and that is by using the OLE Automation stored procedures (i.e. `sp_OA*`). I hesitate to mention these procs as their use is generally frowned upon (for good reason), but am doing so for the sake of completeness only, since if this really is a one-time export (though, how often are projects truly "one time" ;-) ?) then *maybe* this is ok. If you can call them from a T-SQL UDF then you can do something similar to the CLR example I showed above. But, if they are not allowed in a T-SQL UDF (at least not when writing to the filesystem), then you would have to use a `CURSOR` to iterate over the rows. Just FYI, in order to use the `sp_OA*` stored procedures, "OLE Automation" (a server config option) needs to be enabled.